# Telerik RadGrid single-click vs double-click detection

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

I am using the Telerik `RadGrid` control, but whenever I click on the `GridEditCommandColumn` I am receiving a double-click event.

Can someone please clarify for me how to properly detect **single-click** vs **double-click** events for the control?

Comment: If you want someone to help you, please retitle your question properly, show only relevant code and use line breaks. Please also read [faq] and [ask] page.

Comment: what have you written in click or double click events?

Comment: I haven't written double click event.I did only AllowAutomaticInserts="True" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" at rad grid and written insert method by using object data source.

Comment: Please, read this post: [Telerik WinForms: Double clicking not distinguishing with single clicking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652295/telerik-winforms-double-clicking-not-distinguishing-with-single-clicking/43652296#43652296)